# How to tell if you are part of a group text message

Tags: sms

When being texted by another Android user, is there some way to determine whether you are part of a group text or being contacted individually?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when I send the same text to multiple people, if they are in a group chat on their iPhone and add me, then I can see who is texting who (or at least the numbers of the people). If I'm holding a group chat in Google Hangouts I can see the people as well. Otherwise.... There is not way to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Only way I found is by holding down on message and clicking DETAILS then it shows the list of people message went to.  Another giveaway is if the message says REPLY ALL.

Answer (score 0):

Press and hold the text message you received.
A menu will come up with view details at the bottom of the list.
Press on view details, it will show you everything about the text.